# Creating sqlite3 files/database

Tags: database, sqlite

I am struggling to create a database using SQLite3 using Windows 7.

SLite3 is currently installed:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Development\
```

and has sqlite3.def, sqlite3.dll and a sqlite3 (.exe) file.

I have also updated the environment variable of Path to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Development\
```

When I double click:

```
sqlite3.exe
```

It opens up the command prompt with the address at the top as:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Development\sqlite3.exe
```

It opens up and is:

```
"Connected to a transient in-memory database."
(transient in-memory database) is in red text
```

Looking around this means that it saves to memory and not hard disk but if you specify:

```
.save testDB
```

Then all should be good, but not for me. I have tried:

```
sqlite3 testDB.db
.save testDB
create table tbl1(one varchar(10), two smallint);
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: near "sqlite3" syntax error
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I have SQLite manager installed too but I assume I can't use that until a database is saved to disk?

Thanks.

Would changing my Path variable to:

```
C: \Program Files (x86)\Development\
```

Make any difference i.e. a space between : and the \?

Comment: goto the link point number 2. https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same problem and found help [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) on the official website. Essentially, you can double-click on the `sqlite3.exe` file. Then use the `.open` command to get a persistent database. To create your `testDB.db` database, you can do as follows:

```
SQLite version 3.8.8.3 2015-02-25 13:29:11
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .open c:/sqlite/testDB.db
sqlite>
```

This should create `testDB.db` in c:/sqlite or some other folder you specify.

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not need `sqlite3.def` or `sqlite3.dll`.
2. There are two ways if starting the `sqlite3` command-line shell, either by double-clicking on the .exe, or by typing `sqlite3` and any parameters in the Command Prompt.
   Do not try to start `sqlite3` from inside itself.
3. SQLite Manager is able to create a new database.
4. Using a wrong path would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Reach the path where you want to start with SQLite through command prompt, for **e.g. c:\sqlite>**. Now when I use **ls** command I get 
 **c:\sqlite>ls** 
**sqlite3.exe** 
Now to create database type 
**c:\sqlite>sqlite3 database.db** 
 It will create a database for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add sqlite3.exe in a folder, for example: C:\sqlite3\sqlite3.exe
2. Now go to the path where the sqlite3.exe is and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Per the '.help' instructions, type '.save filename'.  When reopening, type '.open filename'.  This worked for me.